# Can I use @Procedure to call an Oracle Function in spring-jpa?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have this Oracle funtion

```
FUNCTION fn_get_vp_id_by_hexstring (mp_hexstring    VARCHAR2,
                                   mp_fp_id        NUMBER,
                                   mp_erf_user     VARCHAR2 DEFAULT USER)
                                   RETURN NUMBER;
```

and I want to call it using the `@Procedure` annotation of [spring-data-jpa](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/).

So I created this repository code:

```
@Procedure(procedureName = "FN_GET_VP_ID_BY_HEXSTRING")
Integer getVpIdByHexString(
    @Param("mp_hexstring") String hexstring,
    @Param("mp_fp_id") Integer fp_id,
    @Param("mp_erf_user") String user);
```

This does not work, since spring assumes `FN_GET_VP_ID_BY_HEXSTRING` is a procedure which means it expects the return value to be an output parameter instead of a return value of the PL/SQL function. So obviously I get this error message (note the **`OUT=>:3`**):

```
Caused by: Error : 6550, Position : 6, Sql = BEGIN FN_GET_VP_ID_BY_HEXSTRING(MP_HEXSTRING=>:0,MP_FP_ID=>:1,MP_ERF_USER=>:2,OUT=>:3); END;, OriginalSql = {call FN_GET_VP_ID_BY_HEXSTRING(?,?,?,?)}, Error Msg = ORA-06550: Zeile 1, Spalte 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'FN_GET_VP_ID_BY_HEXSTRING'
```

Is there a way to use `@Procedure`, or an other annotation to call an Oracle function?

Comment: I looked for the same thing a while ago. After searching the docs and reviewing spring source code, it seems to me that it was not possible at the time.
I currently use `org.springframework.jdbc.object.SotredProcedure` for function calls.
If you find a way to do it, please share it as an answer. Thx.